# Compiler warning about raw type when calling Map#put()

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

I built a Java class that receives a generic objects;

The class only field is set to be:

```
private Map map = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
```

My problem is that during some method I wrote, when I called the `put` method for HashMap object and the compiler warning me and diaplay following message:

> Type safety: The method `put(Object, Object)` belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type `Map<K,V>` should be parameterized

I prefer to avoid a compiler warnings because it might end in a runtime error.

I will be glad if you could explain me the message and what I need to do to eliminate it.

The method I wrote is:

```
public void addItem(T item) {
    if (this.map.containsKey(item)) {
        this.map.put(item, (int)this.map.get(item) + 1);
    }
    else {
        this.map.put(item, 1);
    }
}
```

and here you can see where the compiler complains:

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: I do not believe that you really got the message you are stating. I believe that in fact you get "Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type **Map**".

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
private Map map = new HashMap();
```

to

```
private Map<Type1, Type2> map = new HashMap<>();
```

where `Type1` & `Type2` are the class names for the map's `key` & `value` **(respectively)**

For the example, to declare a map of `String` values indexed by `Integer`s:
*(Notice that you can't use primitive types)*

```
private Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The drawback of your approach can be seen at line 3 of your method where a down cast is needed. Obviously this can lead to a **ClassCastException** in case the key-value pair has been replaced by a different value type. (In this case, you're downcasting to an `int`, which is invalid)

*By parametrizing the map, you are forcing the type of objects to be contained inside (or the type of keys to be used)*

Comment: Your answer is correct, however I'm afraid it does not really help the OP. You are giving him fish instead of giving him fishing rod... I would expect the *actual answer* really explains him the *reason* behind the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The declared type of map is the unparametrized interface, and the compiler checks against the declared type, not the actual type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use generics properly, it is not sufficient if you use them only in the instantiation (= creating a new object by calling the `new` operator) `new HashMap<T,Integer>()`, but you should also *declare* your variables with generics:

```
private Map<T,Integer> map = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
```

Since Java 7, you do not have to repeat the types in the instantiation, because the compiler is smart enough to infer (= deduce) the correct type from the declaration. It means you may write just

```
private Map<T,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The construction `<>` is called a *diamond operator* based on its shape.

Your compiler is complaining about using the `Map` without generics, which is called a *raw type*.

I believe you did not copy the warning message properly. My compiler says

> Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type **Map**.

Notice **Map**, not HashMap. Because the compiler cannot (generally) know what actual instance you have assigned to the `map` variable. Hence the compiler is complaining about raw type of the **variable** `map`, not about its actual **content**.

And the compiler should already complain (unless you have somehow suppressed it) at the declaration

```
private Map map = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
```

> Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map should be parameterized

which is exactly what I wrote. It is always good advice to start reading the warning from the first line they appear.